# Centering a smaller div inside a larger div

Tags: html, css

I've tried to search around for some answers, but still haven't found any.

Basically what I'm trying to do is center my green box within my blue box.

The blue box is 100%, the green is 80%, and I figured I'd just give my green box a margin-left of 10%, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about -- https://imgur.com/xaPttJM

```css
#content_wrapper {
  height: 30rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 30rem;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content_wrapper">
  <div class="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

I've usually been able to do this before, but I must be missing something somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking perfectly centered to me.

Comment: .content  {
margin:0 auto;
}

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="content_wrapper">    
    <div class="content">Your text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content_wrapper {
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
.content {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the quick reply! I tried doing what you wrote, but to no avail; my preview still looks like the image I posted in my original question... :(

Comment: I updated my answer with a different technique. Hope it helps you now.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me fella, but I already solved it, haha... I had *, body {margin: 0 !important; } at the top of my CSS file, removed it, and now my divs are centered! :) But thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
#content_wrapper {
  height: 30rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 30rem;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: green;
  margin:0 auto !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

this will center it horizontally
heres a js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/benF/b4w2yboy/6/

remove `position:absolute;` and set `display:block;` and remove the `margin-left: 10%;` then it should work

NOTE you must have a width set for the `.content` element currently it is `80%`

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the quick response! I tried to actually ctrl+c, ctrl+v your fiddle into my css file, but it still looks like the image i posted in my original question... :(

Comment: is there any other css that is affecting those 2 divs? @treadwell

Comment: Well, the only thing I could think of would be, that I have a html{ margin: 0;} inside my css file, do you think that would have anything to do with it?

Comment: no i dont think so let me edit my  fiddle and question

Comment: can you make a fiddle with all your code so i can take a deeper look at it please @treadwell

Comment: Wait wait wait! I figured it out! Silly me... the first line of my CSS file was *, body { margin: 0 !important;} -- taking the !important out fixed the thing, and my divs are not centered!

Comment: oh ok did my solution help any? @treadwell

Comment: It sure did, it made me go over the CSS file and look for any random css affecting my divs, haha. Thanks for the help fella!

Comment: can you accept my answer please i would really appreciate it @treadwell